# Tradução do privilégio "proteger perguntas"

Tags: bug, tradução, internacionalização

Falta a tradução, na notificação, do privilégio "proteger perguntas". Não sei se faltará mais algum...

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: creio que seja geral, também notei isso no ... `Você ganhou o privilégio "edit questions and answers"! Descubra mais sobre ele na central de ajuda.`